# Fixing loose strap button screw in solid-body guitar

Tags: electric-guitar, maintenance, repair, lutherie

I have a strap button screw in my Squier Affinity Strat that I have to re-fasten every week or so, and I'd like to carry out a more permanent repair. There is no visible damage to the screw hole or the area around it or to the screw itself, it just doesn't fit tightly enough or the wood is too soft. This is a 15-year old Indonesian-made guitar with an [Agathis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agathis) body.

So I'm sat here with my guitar, a box of toothpicks, and a tube of wood glue; how do I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Toothpicks are good for this, no glue required. Gently hammer the first pick in, then another, sharp end first. If there's still a hole, it means using another. Use a sharp blade to trim them. Use the original screw, and it should all fit back tightly. If not, use a slightly longer screw, and if possible, a slightly thicker one, provided it goes through the button. I have occasionally had to drill out the hole in the button a little, to be able to use a wider screw, but that's in desperation.

Answer (score 4):

Put wood glue on a toothpick, break it off clean so nothing sticks out. Side-cutters can help here.

Then screw the button in. The extra wood will give the screw more bite and it won't pull out anymore.

Actually, the glue isn't entirely necessary.

Comment: I like to use the glue just in case. It is a strap button after all.